# Calculate Number of Days between Given time in ISO format and Current time

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have to find out number of days between a given Time and current time. Given time is in **ISO format** and one example is "2021-01-14 16:23:46.217-06:00".

I have tried it using "java.text.SimpleDateFormat" but it's not giving me accurate results.
In Below Given date, for today's time I am getting output as "633" Days which isn't correct. somehow after parsing it is taking date as "21 december 2020" which isn't correct

```
String TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.s-hh:mm" ;  
int noOfDays = Utility.getTimeDifferenceInDays("2021-01-14 16:23:46.217-06:00", TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);
              
public static int getTimeDifferenceInDays(String timestamp, String TIMESTAMP_FORMAT) {

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);
        try {
            Date date = df.parse(timestamp);
            long timeDifference = (System.currentTimeMillis() - date.getTime());
            return (int) (timeDifference / (1000*60*60*24));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Looking for a better solution which gives me correct number of days. Thanks

Comment: **0.** Stop using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, for they are obsolete. **1.** Psrse using `DateTimeFormatter`, with format `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SXXXX`. **2.** Use `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(backThen, now)`.

Comment: @MCEmperor The pattern you've provided would fail to parse the string specified in the question. Because ***1.*** The number of characters in the fractional part doesn't match, it should be `SSS`, not `S`. ***2.*** Offset contains `:` therefore according to the documentation it needs to be represent by `XXX` (or `zzz`), i.e. three characters, not four. See the correct pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73801432/17949945).

Comment: In which time zone do you want to count the days? It matters. The time from yesterday at 23:00 until today at 09:00, does that count as 0 days or 1 day? That is, do the dates count or only full days?

Comment: It’s a wonderful demonstration of the trouble with `SimpleDateFormat`. Less than half of your format pattern string is correct (sorry to say), and yet `SimpleDateFormat` just pretends all is well and gives you absolute garbage as a result. It’s not a behaviour you would want from any class.

Comment: BTW `2021-01-14 16:23:46.217-06:00` is not ISO format. [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) requires a `T` between date and time, not a space, as in `2021-01-14T16:23:46.217-06:00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use java.time API

Classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are legacy.

Since Java 8 (which was released **10** years ago) we have a new Time API, represented by classes from the `java.time` package.

To parse and format the data, you can use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). An instance of `DateTimeFormatter` can be obtained via static method `ofPattern()`, or using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

- `ofPattern()`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
```

- `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.")       // main date-time part
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3) // fraction part of second
    .appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00")            // can be substituted with appendPattern("zzz") or appendPattern("XXX")
    .toFormatter();
```

The string `"2021-01-14 16:23:46.217-06:00"`, which you've provided as an example, contains date-time information and UTC offset. Such data can be represented by [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

To get the number of days between two temporal objects, you can use [`ChronoUnit.between()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)) as *@MC Emperor* has mentioned in the comments.

That's how the whole code might look like:

```
String toParse = "2021-01-14 16:23:46.217-06:00";


    
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(toParse, formatter);
System.out.println("parsed date-time: " + dateTime);
        
Instant now = Instant.now();
        
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateTime.toInstant(), now);
System.out.println("days: " + days);
```

*Output:*

```
parsed date-time: 2021-01-14T16:23:46.217-06:00
days: 615
```

**Note** that since in this case you need only difference in days between the current date instead of `OffsetDateTime` you can use `LocalDateTime`, UTC offset would be ignored while parsing a string. If you decide to do so, then the second argument passed to `ChronoUnit.between()` should be also of type `LocalDateTime`.